# Disable Kernel Lockdown in runtime

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I am using ubuntu 20.04, with kernel 5.8.0-53-generic

I wanted to write to an MSR, and I noticed it failing:

```
markov@sambayon:~$ sudo wrmsr -p 0 432 7
wrmsr: pwrite: Operation not permitted
```

Looking at dmesg, I can see:

```
[54424.913569] Lockdown: wrmsr: raw MSR access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

And then I looked for the [kernel_lockdown manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/kernel_lockdown.7.html), which says:

> If the kernel is appropriately configured, lockdown may be lifted by typing the appropriate sequence on a directly attached physical keyboard.  **For x86 machines, this is SysRq+x.**

I tried pressing `Alt`+`SysRQ`+`x`, and it seems like it doesn't work:

```
[54540.993570] sysrq: HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
```

It looks like ubuntu fails the part about it being "appropriately configured"...

Is there any way to remove the lockdown in runtime without having to disable secure boot?

Comment: For anyone wondering, you can disable secure boot in the UEFI BIOS and it will remove the lockdown. However, I wanted to disable it in runtime without having to reboot nor disable secure boot.

Comment: Partial answer: how to disable lockdown without deactivating secure boot:
I read a very vague explanation here: https://github.com/erpalma/throttled#writing-to-msr-and-pci-bar, but so far it does not work on my machine